# Delete/Clear Neo4j DB for Test serie

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a series of unit test where I need to clear a neo4j database. All the tests pass if I run them individually but when I run them all then some fail saying that a particular node could not be found:

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Node[6] not found.
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getNodeForProxy(NodeManager.java:505)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.hasProperty(NodeProxy.java:151)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.PropertyFieldAccessorFactory$PropertyFieldAccessor.doGetValue(PropertyFieldAccessorFactory.java:85)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ConvertingNodePropertyFieldAccessorFactory$ConvertingNodePropertyFieldAccessor.doGetValue(ConvertingNodePropertyFieldAccessorFactory.java:89)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.PropertyFieldAccessorFactory$PropertyFieldAccessor.getValue(PropertyFieldAccessorFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.getValue(DefaultEntityState.java:97)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DetachedEntityState.getValue(DetachedEntityState.java:100)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DetachedEntityState.getValue(DetachedEntityState.java:105)
```

I have tried this but it didn't solve my problem: [Neo4jDatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-clean-remote-db-addon/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/server/extension/test/delete/Neo4jDatabaseCleaner.java)

What's noticeable is that the tests which have the problem are the one with a relation with properties.

What else could I try?

Comment: can you share your test-code, you shouldn't rely on looking up nodes by fixed id's for verification.

Comment: the @RunsWith(SpringJunit4TestRunner.class) already does the rollback on tearDown.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but the code is big in many classes. Hard to show. Yes, I use @RunsWith(SpringJunit4TestRunner.class)

Answer (score 4):

What about using the [ImpermanentGraphDatabase](http://madgrapher.blogspot.com/2012/06/persisting-to-neo4j-via-spring-data-or.html) that comes with the Neo4j kernel?

Build/destroy the graph without worrying about cleaning up, etc.

Comment: Also could be if you're deleting/altering things in the graph that are persisted between tests.

Answer (score 3):

The way we solve this is by having a context aware abstract class that all unit test classes extend. This method contains a before method that clears our all the data in all defined graph repositories.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext.xml", "/applicationContext-test.xml" })
public abstract class AbstractTestBase {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Before
    public void clearAllGraphRepositories() {
        Map<String, GraphRepository> graphRepositories = ctx.getBeansOfType(GraphRepository.class);
        for (GraphRepository graphRepository : graphRepositories.values()) {
            graphRepository.deleteAll();
        }
    }

}
```

This can obviously easily be modified to only clear specific repositories, but I'll leave that to you... :-)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do this is to run the test trantransactional and roll back after each test?

Comment: Did not help unfortunately. Tried this: 
 @After
 public void after() {
  try {
      tx.failure();
  }
  finally {
      tx.finish();
  }
 }

Comment: I used @Transactional around the JUnit test and then just removed the nodes in a finally block.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this tutorial to set up a test environment:
http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2011/11/development-setup-for-neo4j-and-php.html

the key point is a plugin for neo4j called *test-delete-db-extension-1.8.jar*

or, in gremlin, you can invoke the command g.clear(); (seems to be the same functionality as the plugins').

Comment: when using neo4j on a linux machine, you can always delete the whole test environment and than install the zip package again to get a fresh instance. watch out for the conf/ folder if you are making changes to its files

Comment: try to erase and reinstall the whole instance, then. but that is a temporary solution.  or maybe try the tutorial with another version of neo4j